# UICollectionView Reorder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios9

iOS9 implements a nice reordering feature for the UICollectionView.

At my CollectionViewController I implemented following code to get it work:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath 
{
    _cells[sourceIndexPath.row][1] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)destinationIndexPath.row];
    _cells[destinationIndexPath.row][1] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self saveCellorder];
}
```

**The 'cells' Array is just there to save the order of the Cells in the View**

--

Now to my Problem/Question:

I got 2 different sized Cells in my CollectionView, when I drag a small cell over a small cell they change their places and everything is ok. Same happens when I drag a big cell over a big cell.

BUT when I drag a small cell over a big cell the big cell gets small and the small cell gets big.
How can i prevent the cells from changing their size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you have you delegate method `-collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` implemented. This method returns not a size of *the cell*, strictly saying. It returns *size of a cell  at specified position*. So, you should catch moment, when collection view order changes and respond to it in a manner, that tells `-collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` to return the right size.

Or, you can simply implement **self-sizing** collection view cells. Take a look at WWDC 2014 "What's New in Table and Collection Views". It is pretty easy Amazing©

For more on self-sizing cells : [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/5016443)